# Trigger a callback function via a barcode scan

Tags: python, tkinter, callback, barcode-scanner

I am currently building a dashboard program that keeps track of equipment processes in a laboratory. I am trying to add a script that will trigger a countdown timer when the equipment's barcode is scanned. The dashboard's GUI is built with tKinter.

I have the following script currently, but it is really unreliable and doesn't work about 80% of the barcodes used in the lab:

```
        self.text = ''
        def key(event):
            
            self.text += event.char
            
            print ("pressed", self.text)
            
        def accept_scan(event):
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            if self.text.startswith('EQUIP-'):
                self.text = self.text.lower()
                # self.text = '.' + str(self.text)
                print(self.text)
                target = self.map_canvas.nametowidget(self.text)
                print(target)
                initiate_run(self.text, target, late_time = None)
                
                   
            self.text = ""
            
        master.bind("<Key>", key)
        master.bind("<Return>", accept_scan) AND master.bind("<Tab>", accept_scan)
```

Where EQUIP- is the prefix used by all the equipment barcodes. The rest is reformatting the input to match the tkinter widget name that it references, and `initiate_run` is the callback I want to trigger.

Is there a better way to go about this? I have a feeling that the barcodes use different escape characters or something that I didn't cover in the binding script, but I can't really look at the barcodes to see what they are.

Comment: It seems that it is not a problem of the application program, but an external condition such as the print quality of the barcode, the reading performance of the barcode scanner, and how to hold/read the barcode is more likely.